# How can I make the return-type of a function taking a sequence as input dependent on that sequences types?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I am working on a library able to perform SNMP set operations. There is a function that has a signature like the following:

```
def multiset(ip: str, community: str, oids: List[str], values: List[SnmpValue]) -> List[SnmpValue]:
   ...
```

This is slightly altered to the real signature to illustrate the typing issue a bit better. On normal operations, the function will return the values that were set back as list of the same types. In this example that looks redundant, but in the real code there is a use-case for this (error-detection), but that would make this typing question a bit too convoluted.

The core is that I have a function that takes a sequence of values and returns a sequence of the same types. The types are only really visible on a line that calls that function.

Another way to illustrate this is the code example below:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Union, List


TSupportedTypes = Union[int, str]
T = TypeVar('T', bound=TSupportedTypes)


class Wrapper(Generic[T]):

    def __init__(self, value: T) -> None:
        self.value = value



def process(data: List[Wrapper[TSupportedTypes]]) -> List[TSupportedTypes]:
    output = []
    for item in data:
        output.append(item.value)
    return output


processed = process([Wrapper(1), Wrapper('foo')])

# Is it possible to make this work without an "isinstance" check?
processed[1].startswith('f')
```

In the last time, the type-checker only knows that each value in the list is either an `int` or a `str`. In that case, the types are only known at the time `process` is called.

In the above case, the type-checker complains that `int` has no attribute `startswith`, but the code would work nonetheless.

Is there a way to tell the type-checker that whatever returns from the `process` function is the same as that what went into it?

Currently I use a healthy dose of `Any` hints, but that defeats a good part of the type-checking in this code and I would be really curious to find out if this works.

Comment: Why not group all the possible OIDs and their types into a `TypedDict`(total=False) or a `dataclass` and pass the dict/object around? That way all the OID values are strictly type-checked when assigned.

Comment: That's a really good idea, but I am currently restricted to Python 3.5. With luck that will change in the coming 4-6 months.

Comment: `TypedDict` is available to the older versions of Python via the `typing-extensions` module.

Comment: oooh... nice... it even supports protocols <3 I will definitely give that a go. In any case, I think the `TypedDict` solution will work for my use-case. If you reformat this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't `process` or even `Wrapper`.  The problem is that the list type is considered a homogeneous container type.

`List[X]` means every element of the list is an instance of the same X.

Even this simplified version of your example doesn't type check:

```py
from typing import Union, List

TSupportedTypes = Union[int, str]
processed: List[TSupportedTypes] = [1, 'foo'] 

# Is it possible to make this work without an "isinstance" check?
processed[1].startswith('f')
```

You can see that for the particular *value* in this program, `processed[1].startswith` is safe but if you look at only the *types* - which is what mypy does - then there is no way to know this.  According to the *types* `processed[1]` could be either a str or an int.

Comment: Thanks for replying to this after 2 years. And with 2 more years of typing experience, I now have gathered enough experience to know that I can accept your answer ;)